# How to dynamically output a type for a component in TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, antd

`I have an array with objects in which I compare the type field and, depending on this, return some component, for example input, select, chwckbox, etc. (I use antd). I ran into a problem when declaring types. The type "string | boolean | undefined" cannot be assigned to the type "string | number | readonly string[] | undefined".  I'm converting the value in the parent component to either string or boolean (for now) and I need to combine these types.

```
interface CustomFieldComponentProps<T> {
 customField: CustomFieldDto;
    onChange?: (values: any) => void;
    value?: T;
}

export const CustomFieldTypeComponent = <T extends string | boolean>({
    customField,
    onChange,
    value,
}: CustomFieldComponentProps<T>) => {
    const customFieldAttributes = {
        disabled: customField?.enabled,
    };

    const selectOptions = createOptionsFromDict(
        customField?.defaultValue?.customDictionaries,
    );

    switch (customField.type) {
        case CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE.STR_FIELD:
            return (
                <Input
                    className={styles.customField}
                    placeholder={customField?.textPlaceholder}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    value={value}
                    disabled={customFieldAttributes?.disabled}
                    id={customField?.id}
                />
            );

        case CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE.DROP_LIST:
            return (
                <Select
                    className={styles.customField}
                    disabled={customFieldAttributes?.disabled}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    options={selectOptions}
                    value={value}
                    id={customField?.id}
                />
            );

        case CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE.BOOL_SWITCH:
            return (
                <Switch
                    className={styles.customField}
                    disabled={customFieldAttributes?.disabled}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    checked={value}
                    id={customField?.id}
                />
            );

        case CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE.BOOL_CHECK:
            return (
                <Checkbox
                    className={styles.customField}
                    disabled={customFieldAttributes?.disabled}
                    onChange={(e: CheckboxChangeEvent) => onChange?.(e.target.checked)}
                    checked={value}
                    id={customField?.id}
                />
            );

        case CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE.NUMBER_SPINNER:
            return (
                <InputNumber
                    className={styles.customField}
                    disabled={customFieldAttributes?.disabled}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    value={value}
                    id={customField?.id}
                />
            );

        default:
            return null;
    }
};
```

Here is part of the code from the parent component

```
return (
    <>
        {contextHolder}
        {customFields.map(customField => (
            <FieldItem
                name={['customFields', customField?.field?.id]}
                key={customField?.field?.id}
                initialValue={getDefaultValue(
                    customField?.field?.type,
                    customField?.field?.defaultValue,
                    customField?.value,
                )}
                label={customField?.field?.textTitle || ''}
                htmlFor={customField?.field?.id}
            >
                <CustomFieldTypeComponent<string> customField={customField.field} />
            </FieldItem>
        ))}
    </>
);
```

I tried to output the type via generic and pass it through the parent component, but the error did not disappear`